# Doesn't understand why I get this error when I want use my variable error : lateinit property _mails has not been initialized in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want use my variable _mails that I lateninit in the init in my ViewModel. I can't give the the dataBase access:( I'm trying to get setAdaptater for my AutoCompleteView but when I trying to get the mail by my viewModel it tell me that I have not initialized the variable _mails.

```
class ConnectionViewModel(
    val database: ConnectionDataBaseDao,
    application: Application) :  AndroidViewModel(application){

    private lateinit var _mails : List<Connection>


    init {

        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
           _mails = database.getAllConnections()
    }

    fun getAllConnections():List<Connection> {
        return _mails
    }

}
```

It is in the ConnectionFragment that I call the getAllConnections().

```
class ConnectionFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var viewModel: ConnectionViewModel

private lateinit var viewModelFactory: ConnectionViewModelFactory

private lateinit var binding: FragmentConnectionBinding

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,
        R.layout.fragment_connection,container,false)

    val application = requireNotNull(this.activity).application

    val dataSource = ConnectionDataBase.getInstance(application).connectionDataBaseDao

    viewModelFactory = ConnectionViewModelFactory(dataSource, application)

    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this,viewModelFactory).get(ConnectionViewModel::class.java)

    binding.connectionViewModel = viewModel

    binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner

    return binding.root
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()

    var mails = ArrayList<String>()
    viewModel.getAllConnections().forEach { mails.add(it.mailId) }
    val adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this.requireContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mails)
    binding.mail.setAdapter(adapter)

}
```

}

There is the log error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.soccerinfo, PID: 9206
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property _mails has not been initialized
    at com.example.soccerinfo.connection.ConnectionViewModel.getAllConnections(ConnectionViewModel.kt:65)
    at com.example.soccerinfo.connection.ConnectionFragment.onStart(ConnectionFragment.kt:118)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2731)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.start(FragmentStateManager.java:365)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1206)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1368)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1446)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1509)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2637)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:2595)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2740)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.start(FragmentStateManager.java:365)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1206)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1368)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1446)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1509)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2637)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:2595)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchStart(FragmentController.java:258)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:550)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:210)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1391)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:2937)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:180)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:165)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:142)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database access is an async operation, so it may take some time to complete. But you are trying to access the `_mails` property in onStart using `viewModel.getAllConnections().forEach { mails.add(it.mailId) }`. If database operation is not yet complete then `_mails` property is not initilized and you get the error

**There are many ways to solve this issue.**

### Make database method return LiveData

if you are using Room database then you can make `database.getAllConnections()` return `LiveData<List<Connection>>` and then you can observe this in your fragment as

```
viewModel.getAllConnections().observe(this, Observer{
// here you receive the result of database.getAllConnections
}
// viewModel.getAllConnections() = database.getAllConnections
```

### Change type of `_mails` to `MutableLiveData<List<Connection>>`

```
class ConnectionViewModel(
val database: ConnectionDataBaseDao,
application: Application) :  AndroidViewModel(application){

    val mails : MutableLiveData<List<Connection>> = MutableLiveData()
    init {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
          _mails.postValue(database.getAllConnections())
    }
}
```

And now you can observe _mails in your Fragment as

```
viewModel.mails.observe(this, Observer{
  // here you receive the result of database.getAllConnections
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, It's working, I just have one question, why do I have to use an observer?

Comment: instead of waiting for a function to return result, you just register an observer and the observer is notified when data is ready. This allows you to write code that doesn't block